# Is there any way for setting up mongodb as a server with vagrantfile?

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, windows-7-x64

Currently I have environment below:
- Windows 7 64 bits
- Vagrant
- Virtual Box
- Nodejs
- Webdriverio
- Chai
- Appium

I would like to build a database server (using mongodb) with vagrant that I will connect from my PC as a client. Then I can run my script to create test data on this database.
I will use only **one PC** for both server (virtual machine) and client (physical machine).

Is it possible to build this idea? And how to implement it? 
Please give me some advice if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are vagrant images with preinstalled MongoDb like this one
https://app.vagrantup.com/dansweeting/boxes/ubuntu-trusty64-mongo-node

Create a vagrant file
EX:

```
# created by Andrei Lupuleasa, December 2018.
Vagrant.require_version ">= 2.2.2"

# Automatically installs required plugin on Windows
if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
  plugin = 'vagrant-winnfsd'

  system "vagrant plugin install #{plugin}" unless Vagrant.has_plugin?(plugin)
end

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box      = "dansweeting/ubuntu-trusty64-mongo-node" # VM OS version
  config.vm.hostname = "vagrantdev"

  # set IP and ports
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.44.10"

  # Sync the sources folder with the machine
  # For Windows `nfs` is preferred due to poor performance of default settings.
  if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
    config.vm.synced_folder "share", "/var/www/html", type: 'nfs'
  else
    config.vm.synced_folder "share", "/var/www/html", mount_options: ["dmode=777","fmode=777"]
  end

  # Set to true if you want automatic checks
  config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Copy personal private key with access to repository to machine
  config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.ssh/id_rsa", destination: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"  
  config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", destination: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"

end
```

Go where you have your vagrant file from cmd like
`cd D:\vagrant` and do `vagrant up`